# Software Dictionary for Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, dictionary, software

I have a Windows Mobile 6.5 Phone (LG Fathom) and I would like to load a free English to German and German to English dictionary on it to assist me in learning German. (I go to classes every weekend) I've tried searching a few sites but no luck. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think this question is off topic here.

Comment: I put this in Stackoverflow and I get downvoted for the same reason!

Comment: @LegolasGreenleaf On Stackoverflow it is off-topic for sure. In my opinion it's also off-topic here, since we're talking about the language and its usage, but since there is no better sister site I guess those questions are acceptable.

Comment: What about http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [LEO](http://dict.leo.org/pages.ende/smartphones_en.html?lp=ende&lang=en)? Not sure, but the PDA version they offer might work for you.

Comment: nice, I didn't know they had apps for even quite obscure mobile operating systems.

Comment: Their PDA version is online so it won't work. I need an offline software.